# Limiting window size in Java

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I am working on a program for a class that I am taking. The program I am creating is a game. The program has a main class that extends frame. Inside that class I created a window that is setup as a border layout. In the CENTER of the border layout is a panel that also has a border layout. My second class, which extends canvas, is assigned to the second border layout's CENTER. In that canvas, I have an object that moves around the screen using the keyboard. Say for instance the following is my window and the O is the object moving around:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|File____________________________________________________X_|
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                          O               |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|                                                          |
|__________________________________________________________|
```

Is there a way to restrict the size of the window based on where the O is? I don't want to resize smaller than where the object is being rendered. If it matters, the O is stored as a Rectangle Object, and so is the border of the CENTER of the second border layout. I have the O staying in the border by using the Rectangle.contains method. After the O moves away from the border, I want the allowable size to be restricted even further.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import static java.lang.Integer.min;

public class BouncingBall extends Frame
implements ActionListener, WindowListener, ComponentListener, AdjustmentListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, Runnable {

private boolean done = false;
Thread theThread;

int sbVis = 10;
int sbMin = 1;
int sbMax = 100 + sbVis;
int sbUnitInc = 3;
int sbBlockInc = 20;
private final int DELAY = 10;
long delay = (long)(DELAY*(double)((sbMax - sbMin)/100));

private Panel canvas = new Panel();
private Panel control = new Panel();

Scrollbar speedSB;
Scrollbar sizeSB;
Button runBtn;
Button pauseBtn;
Button quitBtn;
Label speedLabel;
Label sizeLabel;
Screen s = new Screen();

Rectangle ZERORECT = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
private boolean newRect = true;
int x1, x2, y1, y2;


BouncingBall () {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    canvas.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
    start();
}

//main function
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BouncingBall b = new BouncingBall();
} //end main function

private void initComponents () {
    //set up main frame layout and add the components to the correct location
    this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
    this.setSize(640,480);
    //this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    s.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //mouse listeners
    s.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    s.addMouseListener(this);

    //listeners on this frame
    this.addComponentListener(this);
    this.addWindowListener(this);

    //add buttons, scrollbars, and labels
    speedSB = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL);
    speedSB.setMinimum(sbMin);
    speedSB.setMaximum(sbMax);
    speedSB.setVisibleAmount(sbVis);
    speedSB.setUnitIncrement(sbUnitInc);
    speedSB.setBlockIncrement(sbBlockInc);
    speedSB.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    sizeSB = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL);
    sizeSB.setMinimum(15);
    sizeSB.setMaximum(sbMax);
    sizeSB.setVisibleAmount(sbVis);
    sizeSB.setUnitIncrement(sbUnitInc);
    sizeSB.setBlockIncrement(sbBlockInc);
    sizeSB.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    sizeSB.setValue(s.ball.width);
    runBtn = new Button("Run");
    runBtn.addActionListener(this);
    runBtn.setEnabled(false);
    pauseBtn = new Button("Pause");
    pauseBtn.addActionListener(this);
    quitBtn = new Button("Quit");
    quitBtn.addActionListener(this);
    speedLabel = new Label("Speed");
    sizeLabel = new Label("Size");


    //setup the layout of the control panel
    GridBagLayout lm = new GridBagLayout();
    control.setLayout(lm);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,30,5,30);
    control.add(speedSB, c);

    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,5,0);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    control.add(runBtn, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    control.add(pauseBtn, c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 0;
    control.add(quitBtn, c);

    c.insets = new Insets(10,30,5,30);
    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 0;
    control.add(sizeSB, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    control.add(speedLabel, c);

    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 1;
    control.add(sizeLabel, c);
    s.repaint();
}

public Rectangle makeRect () {
    int width = this.x1 - this.x2;
    int height = this.y1 - this.y2;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(min(this.x1, this.x2),min(this.y1,this.y2),Math.abs(width),Math.abs(height));
    return rect;
}

public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    while (true) {
        try {
            theThread.sleep(0);
            while (!done) {//pause variable
                s.step();
                this.setMinimumSize(s.getMinimumSize());
                try {
                    theThread.sleep(delay); //move speed
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
}

public void start() { //begin overloaded start()
    if (theThread == null) {
        theThread = new Thread(this);
        theThread.start();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    this.removeWindowListener(this);
    this.removeComponentListener(this);
    sizeSB.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    speedSB.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    s.removeMouseListener(this);
    s.removeMouseMotionListener(this);
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}//end stop()

//canvas object
public class Screen extends Canvas {
    Image buffer;
    Graphics og;
    Rectangle ball;
    Rectangle screen;
    int x = 1;
    int y = -1;
    Vector<Rectangle> rects = new Vector<Rectangle>();
    public Screen() {
        ball = new Rectangle(10,38,30,30);
        screen = new Rectangle();
    }

    public int ballX() {
        return ball.x;
    }

    public int ballY() {
        return ball.y;
    }

    public void addOne(Rectangle r) {
        Rectangle nr = new Rectangle(r);
        if (!nr.intersects(ball)) {
            if (nr.x + nr.width > screen.width-1) {
                nr.setSize((screen.width-1) - nr.x, nr.height);
            }
            if (nr.y + nr.height > screen.height-1) {
                nr.setSize(nr.width, (screen.height-1) - nr.y);
            }
            rects.addElement(nr);
        }
    }

    public void checkRemove (Point p) {
        Point np = new Point(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            if (rects.get(i).contains(np)) {
                rects.removeElementAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void step () {
        checkBorder();
        checkTouching();
        repaint();
    }

    public void checkBorder() {
        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(ball);
        temp.grow(2,2);
        if (screen.contains(temp)) {
            ball.setLocation((int) ball.getX() + x, (int) ball.getY() + y);
        }
        else {
            if (ball.x + ball.width > screen.width-3) {
                x = -1;
            }
            if (ball.y + ball.height > screen.height-3) {
                y = -1;
            }
            if (ball.x < screen.x+2) {
                x = 1;
            }
            if (ball.y < screen.y+2) {
                y = 1;
            }
            ball.setLocation(ball.x + x, ball.y + y);
        }
    }

    public void checkTouching() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("size: " + getMinimumSize().width);
            Rectangle b = new Rectangle(ball);
            b.grow(1,1);
            if(rects.get(i).intersects(b)) {
                int left = rects.get(i).x;
                int top = rects.get(i).y;
                int right = rects.get(i).x + rects.get(i).width;
                int bottom = rects.get(i).y + rects.get(i).height;
                if ((b.x + b.width) > left) {
                    System.out.println("x = " + x);
                    x=x * -1;
                    System.out.println("left");
                    System.out.println("x = " + x);
                }
                else if ((b.x < right)) {
                    System.out.println("right");
                    x=x * -1;
                }
                else if ((b.y + b.height) > top) {
                    System.out.println("top");
                    y=y * -1;
                }
                else if (b.y < bottom) {
                    System.out.println("bottom");
                    y=y * -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setObjSize (int size) {
        ball.setSize(size,size);
    }

    public void resized() {
        screen.setBounds(this.getBounds());
        if (ball.x + ball.width > screen.width-3) {
            ball.setLocation(screen.width-ball.width-3,ball.y);
        }
        if (ball.y + ball.height > screen.height-3) {
            ball.setLocation(ball.x,screen.height-ball.height-3);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        update(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (og != null) {
            og.dispose();
        }
        buffer = createImage(screen.width, screen.height);
        og = buffer.getGraphics();
        super.paint(g);

        Rectangle rect = makeRect();
        og.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (!newRect) {
            og.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
        }
        for (Rectangle drawRect : this.rects) {
            og.fillRect(drawRect.x,drawRect.y,drawRect.width,drawRect.height);
        }

        //draw the screen border
        og.setColor(Color.RED);
        og.drawRect(screen.x,screen.y,screen.width-1,screen.height-1);
        //draw the ball
        og.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        og.fillOval(ball.x,ball.y,ball.width,ball.height);
        og.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        og.drawOval(ball.x,ball.y,ball.width,ball.height);
        g.drawImage(buffer,0,0,null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        for(Rectangle temp : this.rects) {

        }
    }
}

//overloaded listeners
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();
    if (o == quitBtn) {
        stop();
    }
    else if (o == runBtn) {
        done = false;
        runBtn.setEnabled(false);
        pauseBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if (o == pauseBtn) {
        done = true;
        runBtn.setEnabled(true);
        pauseBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();
    if (obj == sizeSB) {
        int objSize;
        int maxSize = min(s.getWidth()-s.ballX(), s.getHeight()-s.ballY());
        if(maxSize > e.getValue()) {
            objSize = e.getValue();
            s.setObjSize(objSize);
        }
        else {
            objSize = maxSize;
            s.setObjSize(objSize);
            sizeSB.setValue(objSize);
        }
    }
    if (obj == speedSB) {
        int speed = e.getValue();
        delay = (long) (DELAY*(double)(sbMax - speed + 1)/100);
        theThread.interrupt();
    }
}

public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    s.resized();
    System.out.println(s.getHeight());
}

public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

}

public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

}

public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = new Point(e.getX(),e.getY());
    s.checkRemove(p);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x1 = e.getX();
    this.y1 = e.getY();
    System.out.println("x1 = " + x1);
    System.out.println("y1 = " + y1);
    s.repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x2 = e.getX();
    this.y2 = e.getY();
    Rectangle rect = makeRect();
    if (rect.height != 0 || rect.width != 0) {
        s.addOne(rect);
    }
    x1 = 0;
    x2 = 0;
    y1 = 0;
    y2 = 0;
    this.newRect = true;
    s.repaint();
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x2 = e.getX();
    this.y2 = e.getY();
    this.newRect = false;
    s.repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    stop();
}

public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

}

public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

}
//end overloaded listeners
```

}

Comment: Have you considering trying to use `getMinimumSize`, probably overriding it from the `Canvas` class?

Comment: I have considered it, but I am unsure how it will work. I have two rectangles being painted in the canvas. How will this work?

Comment: That all depends on how you’ve coded it - since we don’t have that information, it’s all just guess work on our part

Comment: I've updated the question to include the code. Some of the code is not yet working :) I started adding some code that I thought might make use of the getMinimumSize method.

Comment: Okay, so far, you're getting 0 benefit out of using `java.awt.Panel` and a whole bunch of overhead. Any reason why you're not using at least Swing?

Comment: AWT is required by the instructor. If it was up to me, I'd be learning JavaFX or Swing. His words: "If you can learn this, you can learn anything, because it is all built off of it"

Comment: JavaFX isn't (built off of it) ;)

Comment: His words, not mine.

Comment: Okay, so I've had a little play around with your code, tidied it up a bit and don't see an issue

Comment: That is, if I resize the window, the ball bounces off the new screen bounds

Comment: That’s not the issue. The program also lets you drag a rectangle on the canvas with the mouse. I want to restrict the size to the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: So, you want to resize the "rectangles"? Then you need to know more information. In particular, what the original size of the window was when they were created. From that you can calculate an appropriate scaling ratio and resize them

Comment: No, I don’t want to resize the rectangle. I want to limit the size of the screen to not go beyond the rectangles

Comment: Ahhh, okay, clarity :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer is this something that is possible? ...I am sure anything is possible...

Comment: I can get it to partially work, still investigating

Comment: @MadProgrammer, any update? If you can't figure it out it's fine. It seems that it might not be doable. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to find something a little more elegant, but couldn't quite make it work the way it should, so I ended up with a brute force method.

Basically, this adds a `ComponentListener` to the `Frame` and monitors for it's `componentResized` event.  It then compares the frame's size with the contents `minimumSize` and makes sure that the size is never reduced beyond it (also taking into account the frame's borders).

I know this is in Swing, but the basic concept should apply to AWT

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                    private boolean ignoreNext = false;
                    @Override
                    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                        if (ignoreNext) {
                            ignoreNext = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
                        ignoreNext = true;
                        int width = Math.max(frame.getWidth(), frame.getContentPane().getMinimumSize().width + (insets.left + insets.right));
                        int height = Math.max(frame.getHeight(), frame.getContentPane().getMinimumSize().height + (insets.top + insets.bottom));
                        frame.setSize(width, height);
                    }
                });
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle rect;

        public TestPane() {
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
                private Point anchor;

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int minX = Math.min(anchor.x, p.x);
                    int minY = Math.min(anchor.y, p.y);
                    int maxX = Math.max(anchor.x, p.x);
                    int maxY = Math.max(anchor.y, p.y);

                    rect = new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    anchor = e.getPoint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    anchor = null;
                }
            };
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
            addMouseListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            if (rect == null) {
                return super.getMinimumSize();
            }
            Dimension size = new Dimension(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (rect == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(rect);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

## Updated based on available code...

Okay, that took longer then it should have.  I had to take your code apart and put it back together again.  There were a number of fundamental mistakes and some "hard to find" assignments which kept giving mean erroneous results.

First, `update` calls `paint`, so your "painting" routine is backwards.  `update` should make sure that there is a offscreen buffer available and create one if required and then painting should be done to it's `Graphics` context.  I've played around with it a little and used a `BufferedImage` instead ... because I'm lazy and it's a lot easier to deal with it.

Second, you `MouseListener`s should be registered internally with the `Screen`, the functionality it's trying to achieve is maintained internally by the class.

Calculating the minimum size based on the available `Rectangle`s could be a little complicated, the basic idea is you want to combine them all together into one "super" shape and calculate it's bounds, lucky for you, a class exists to do that...

```
Area area = new Area();
for (Rectangle temp : this.rects) {
    System.out.println(temp);
    area.add(new Area(temp));
}
Rectangle bounds = area.getBounds();
System.out.println("bounds = " + bounds);
Dimension size = new Dimension(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y + bounds.height);
```

Finally, after more mucky about then I really would like, I ended up with an observer pattern which triggers a notification when the "size constraint" may have changed.  The `Frame` then needs to calculate it's minimum size based on the available information it has (including both the `Screen`, `controls` and frame `Insets` to determine it's minimums size...

So, you know, really easy :P

### BouncingBall

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Scrollbar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

public class BouncingBall extends Frame
                implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener, Runnable {

    private boolean done = false;
    Thread theThread;

    int sbVis = 10;
    int sbMin = 1;
    int sbMax = 100 + sbVis;
    int sbUnitInc = 3;
    int sbBlockInc = 20;
    private final int DELAY = 10;
    long delay = (long) (DELAY * (double) ((sbMax - sbMin) / 100));

//  private Panel canvas = new Panel();
    private Panel control = new Panel();

    Scrollbar speedSB;
    Scrollbar sizeSB;
    Button runBtn;
    Button pauseBtn;
    Button quitBtn;
    Label speedLabel;
    Label sizeLabel;
    Screen s = new Screen();

    Rectangle ZERORECT = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private boolean newRect = true;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    BouncingBall() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//      canvas.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        this.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

//main function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BouncingBall b = new BouncingBall();
    } //end main function

    private void initComponents() {
        //set up main frame layout and add the components to the correct location
        this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
        this.setSize(640, 480);

        this.add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        s.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        s.setConstraintListener(new Screen.ConstraintListener() {
            @Override
            public void constraintsChanged(Dimension size) {
                System.out.println("Size = " + size);
                Insets insets = getInsets();
                int minWidth = size.width + (insets.left + insets.right);
                int minHeight = size.height + control.getPreferredSize().height + (insets.top + insets.bottom);
                System.out.println(minWidth + " - " + minHeight);
                setMinimumSize(new Dimension(minWidth, minHeight));
            }
        });

//      canvas.add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //listeners on this frame
//      this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
//          private boolean ignoreNext = false;
//          @Override
//          public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
//              if (ignoreNext) {
//                  ignoreNext = false;
//                  return;
//              }
//              Insets insets = getInsets();
//              ignoreNext = true;
//              int minWidth = canvas.getMinimumSize().width;
//              int minHeight = canvas.getMinimumSize().height + control.getPreferredSize().height;
//              int width = Math.max(getWidth(), minWidth + (insets.left + insets.right));
//              int height = Math.max(getHeight(), minHeight + (insets.top + insets.bottom));
//              setSize(width, height);
//          }
//      });
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });

        //add buttons, scrollbars, and labels
        speedSB = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL);
        speedSB.setMinimum(sbMin);
        speedSB.setMaximum(sbMax);
        speedSB.setVisibleAmount(sbVis);
        speedSB.setUnitIncrement(sbUnitInc);
        speedSB.setBlockIncrement(sbBlockInc);
        speedSB.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        sizeSB = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL);
        sizeSB.setMinimum(15);
        sizeSB.setMaximum(sbMax);
        sizeSB.setVisibleAmount(sbVis);
        sizeSB.setUnitIncrement(sbUnitInc);
        sizeSB.setBlockIncrement(sbBlockInc);
        sizeSB.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        sizeSB.setValue(s.ball.width);
        runBtn = new Button("Run");
        runBtn.addActionListener(this);
        runBtn.setEnabled(false);
        pauseBtn = new Button("Pause");
        pauseBtn.addActionListener(this);
        quitBtn = new Button("Quit");
        quitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        speedLabel = new Label("Speed");
        sizeLabel = new Label("Size");

        //setup the layout of the control panel
        GridBagLayout lm = new GridBagLayout();
        control.setLayout(lm);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 30, 5, 30);
        control.add(speedSB, c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 5, 0);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        control.add(runBtn, c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        control.add(pauseBtn, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        control.add(quitBtn, c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 30, 5, 30);
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 0;
        control.add(sizeSB, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        control.add(speedLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 1;
        control.add(sizeLabel, c);
        s.repaint();
    }

    public Rectangle makeRect() {
        int width = this.x1 - this.x2;
        int height = this.y1 - this.y2;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(min(this.x1, this.x2), min(this.y1, this.y2), Math.abs(width), Math.abs(height));
        return rect;
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        while (true) {
            try {
                theThread.sleep(0);
                while (!done) {//pause variable
                    s.step();
                    try {
                        theThread.sleep(delay); //move speed
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() { //begin overloaded start()
        if (theThread == null) {
            theThread = new Thread(this);
            theThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        sizeSB.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
        speedSB.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }//end stop()

//canvas object
//overloaded listeners
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if (o == quitBtn) {
            stop();
        } else if (o == runBtn) {
            done = false;
            runBtn.setEnabled(false);
            pauseBtn.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (o == pauseBtn) {
            done = true;
            runBtn.setEnabled(true);
            pauseBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        Object obj = e.getSource();
        if (obj == sizeSB) {
            int objSize;
            int maxSize = min(s.getWidth() - s.ballX(), s.getHeight() - s.ballY());
            if (maxSize > e.getValue()) {
                objSize = e.getValue();
                s.setObjSize(objSize);
            } else {
                objSize = maxSize;
                s.setObjSize(objSize);
                sizeSB.setValue(objSize);
            }
        }
        if (obj == speedSB) {
            int speed = e.getValue();
            delay = (long) (DELAY * (double) (sbMax - speed + 1) / 100);
            theThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
//end overloaded listeners
}
```

### Screen

```
//canvas object
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Screen extends Canvas {

    Rectangle ball;
    Vector<Rectangle> rects = new Vector<Rectangle>();
    int x = 1;
    int y = -1;

    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Rectangle temp;

    public Screen() {
        ball = new Rectangle(10, 38, 30, 30);

        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

            private Point anchor;

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                checkRemove(p);
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                anchor = new Point(e.getPoint());
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                anchor = null;
                if (temp != null) {
                    addOne(temp);
                }
                temp = null;
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                int minX = Math.min(anchor.x, p.x);
                int minY = Math.min(anchor.y, p.y);
                int maxX = Math.max(anchor.x, p.x);
                int maxY = Math.max(anchor.y, p.y);

                temp = new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
                repaint();
            }
        };
        addMouseListener(ma);
        addMouseMotionListener(ma);
    }

    public int ballX() {
        return ball.x;
    }

    public int ballY() {
        return ball.y;
    }

    public void addOne(Rectangle r) {
        Rectangle nr = new Rectangle(r);
        if (!nr.intersects(ball)) {
            if (nr.x + nr.width > getWidth() - 1) {
                nr.setSize((getWidth() - 1) - nr.x, nr.height);
            }
            if (nr.y + nr.height > getHeight() - 1) {
                nr.setSize(nr.width, (getHeight() - 1) - nr.y);
            }
            rects.addElement(nr);
        }
        setMinimumSize(calculateMinimumSize());
        constraintsChanged();
    }

    public void checkRemove(Point p) {
        Point np = new Point(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            if (rects.get(i).contains(np)) {
                rects.removeElementAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        setMinimumSize(calculateMinimumSize());
        constraintsChanged();
    }

    public void step() {
        checkBorder();
        checkTouching();
        repaint();
    }

    public void checkBorder() {
        Rectangle tempBall = new Rectangle(ball);
        tempBall.grow(2, 2);
        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), getSize());
        if (screen.contains(tempBall)) {
            ball.setLocation((int) ball.getX() + x, (int) ball.getY() + y);
        } else {
            if (ball.x + ball.width > screen.width - 3) {
                x = -1;
            }
            if (ball.y + ball.height > screen.height - 3) {
                y = -1;
            }
            if (ball.x < screen.x + 2) {
                x = 1;
            }
            if (ball.y < screen.y + 2) {
                y = 1;
            }
            ball.setLocation(ball.x + x, ball.y + y);
        }
    }

    public void checkTouching() {
        if (temp != null) {
            rects.add(temp);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle b = new Rectangle(ball);
            b.grow(1, 1);
            if (rects.get(i).intersects(b)) {
                int left = rects.get(i).x;
                int top = rects.get(i).y;
                int right = rects.get(i).x + rects.get(i).width;
                int bottom = rects.get(i).y + rects.get(i).height;
                if ((b.x + b.width) > left) {
                    x = x * -1;
                } else if ((b.x < right)) {
                    x = x * -1;
                } else if ((b.y + b.height) > top) {
                    y = y * -1;
                } else if (b.y < bottom) {
                    y = y * -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (temp != null) {
            rects.remove(temp);
        }
    }

    public void setObjSize(int size) {
        ball.setSize(size, size);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate(); 
        buffer = null;
        resized();
    }

    public void resized() {
        if (ball.x + ball.width > getWidth() - 3) {
            ball.setLocation(getWidth() - ball.width - 3, ball.y);
        }
        if (ball.y + ball.height > getHeight() - 3) {
            ball.setLocation(ball.x, getHeight() - ball.height - 3);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        super.paint(g2d);
        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (temp != null) {
            g2d.fill(temp);
        }
        for (Rectangle drawRect : this.rects) {
            g2d.fill(drawRect);
        }

        //draw the screen border
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        //draw the ball
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fillOval(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawOval(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (buffer == null) {
            buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
        super.update(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    protected Dimension calculateMinimumSize() {
        Area area = new Area();
        for (Rectangle temp : this.rects) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            area.add(new Area(temp));
        }
        Rectangle bounds = area.getBounds();
        System.out.println("bounds = " + bounds);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y + bounds.height);
        return size;
    }

    public interface ConstraintListener {
        public void constraintsChanged(Dimension size);
    }

    private ConstraintListener listener;

    public void setConstraintListener(ConstraintListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected void constraintsChanged() {
        if (listener == null) {
            return;
        }
        listener.constraintsChanged(getMinimumSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something like that before, but it jumps around a lot and then ends up being smaller than the rectangle anyway. Can you dynamically set minimumSize?

Comment: @Nick I kind of investigated that path without success

Comment: The professor for the class seems to think that this is possible without the jumping around. But, when I and others have asked him, its like it's a secret on how to do it. I do appreciate you helping me try to find a solution.

Comment: First, the provided example doesn’t bounce around for me. SetMininumSize (on the frame) is platform independent and didn’t work for me, and setting it on the component had no effect

Comment: Thank you for your help. appreciate everything you've done. This is a lot more work than I anticipated for the answer :)